# Why is my code error not stopping the function in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My self and another developer are working on an API using `node.js` and we are not advanced coders yet. We ran into problem. I will try and explain the problem here with sample references.

We have an API route that would be called on the frontend, please this is just a sample and not the real code. client said the codes should be private. We want to stop the function when an error is detected in another function we called. I am sure that we are not doing it rightly. Here is the API route for this post request and we called another function that we exported and imported here.

We simply want the `httpCreateHarsh` function to end if there is an error in the `anotherFunction`. With what we have, the error is seen in `console.log` when the user is not an `admin` for example but the `httpCreateHarsh`function keeps running until it reaches the last line. Is this possible? Or is there another way we can structure the code to achieve this?

Shared sample of my code

```js
const callAnotherFunction = require("../anotherfunction")
const httpCreateHarsh = async(req, res) => {
  await callAnotherFunction(req, res);
  return res.status(200).json('created')
}
//This is the second function we called:
const obj = {
  status: 'success',
  code: '244'
}
const anotherFunction = async(req, res) => {
  if (req.body.user !== 'admin') {
    return res.status(401).json('Unauthorized')
  }
  return obj
}
export default = anotherFunction
//The route here:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const httpCreateHarsh = require('../httpCreateHarsh');
router.post("/harsh", httpCreateHarsh)
```

Comment: `asyn` and not `async`, `const anotherFunction = asyn(req, res)=>{`

Comment: It was a typo error, will correct now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is you can wrap the code in `httpCreateHarsh` in an `try...catch` so whenever there is error inside it it will trigger the `catch` block and u exit the api.

```
const httpCreateHarsh = async(req, res)=>{
   try{
       await callAnotherFunction(req, res);

       return res.status(200).json('created')
   } catch(err){
         return res.status(401).json('Unauthorized')
   }
}
```

As an addition to this code you can return a promise from `anotherFunction` so that the `catch` block will be triggered once the promise is rejected.

***For Exmaple:***

```
const anotherFunction = async(req, res) => {
  return new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
    if (req.body.user !== 'admin') {
    myReject();
  }

  myResolve(obj);
  });
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't return the res object in your second function.

To solve this problem you could throw exceptions and catch them in your handler function.

```js
// request handler function
const httpCreateHarsh = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        await callAnotherFunction(req, res);
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(401).json('Unauthorized')
    }

    return res.status(200).json('created')

}

const anotherFunction = asyn(req, res) => {
    if (req.body.user !== 'admin') {
        throw new Error('Unauthorized')
    }
    return obj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code runs as you want it, it will generate the "cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" error, because you will be returning 2 responses
the first will be "unauthorized" by "anotherFunction" function and then the other response which is "created" of the current function "httpCreateHarsh".

what you should do instead is to call the "anotherFunction" as a middleware before moving to the "httpCreateHarsh" function.

it can be done this way:

```
// anotherfunction.js file containing the function you want to import

module.exports = {
   async anotherFunction(req, res) {
      if (req.body.user !== 'admin') {
         return res.status(401).json('Unauthorized')
      }

      // this way, you can access this object from the "httpCreateHarsh" function by using req.body.obj

      req.body.obj =  {
        status: 'success',
        code: '244'
      }

   // this next indicates that there were no errors, and the next function will be called
      next();
   }
}


const httpCreateHarsh = async(req, res) => {
   // do wathever you want here

   return res.status(200).json('created')
}

//The route here:
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const httpCreateHarsh = require('../httpCreateHarsh');
const callAnotherFunction = require("../anotherfunction")

router.post("/harsh", (req, res, next) => callAnotherFunction(req, res, next), httpCreateHarsh)
```